# Sum values that are in column B. Only when there are same value in column A

Tags: excel

Column **A** has reference numbers. Column **B** has their respective values. If there are same reference numbers in column A how to sum their values from column B and sort them ?

**Example turn this :**

- .**A** ................**B**
- 100  ....... 10.00
- 100 ........15.00
- 200 ........30.00
- 300 .......15.50

**Into this :**

- ..**A**............**B**
- 100 ......25.00
- 200.......30.00
- 300.......15.50

Comment: What is this supposed to be in? SQL? At least tell us what you're trying to do in detail.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus It is not what i want. I only want to sum some row values in col B if there are same value in col A rows. See in my example it only needs to sum B1 and B2 because there is same value in A1 and A2.

Answer (score 0):

Sort on A then select A:B, DATA > Outline - [Subtotal](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/calculating-subtotals-and-working-with-levels-in-excel-HA001109798.aspx) and with luck the default settings will suit. If you want to remove the detail then Copy and Paste Special Values over the top, filter to select for ColumnA does not contain `tot`, delete visible other than labels and unfilter. Delete last row if not required and replace `Total` with nothing, if not required. Ungroup if desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RunSummary()
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim rngCursor As Range
    Dim strKey As String
    Dim dblValue As Double

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set rngTable = Range("C3:D6") ' assuming your table is in Range(C3:D6)

    'insert value into dictionary
    For Each rngCursor In rngTable.Rows
        strKey = rngCursor.Cells(1, 1).Value
        dblValue = rngCursor.Cells(1, 2).Value

        'if the key already exists, add the current value to the existing value
        If dict.Exists(strKey) Then
            dict.Item(strKey) = dict.Item(strKey) + dblValue
        Else
        dict.Add strKey, dblValue
        End If

    Next

    'printing the dictionary at cell C9
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rngOutput As Range
    Set rngOutput = Range("C9")
    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In dict.Keys
            rngOutput.Offset(i, 0).Value = key
            rngOutput.Offset(i, 1).Value = dict(key)
    i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```